# Edge browser XMLHttpRequest abort is not working

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var method = "GET";
var url = "https://developer.mozilla.org/";
xhr.open(method,url,true);
xhr.send();
xhr.abort();
```

When i run this code in Microsoft edge browser **xhr** call abort is not working. I test this code in Chrome and Mozilla, its working fine.

Comment: Do you get any specific error ?

Comment: I just inspect the window i can see the call is canceled in all other browsers not in edge

Comment: This is my fiddile url https://jsfiddle.net/hs29s7vn/

Answer (score 0):

I faced this same issue, this is a bug in Edge.
 https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/14673124/